# jQuery plugin to make round selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need something simulat jcrop plucgin (link to example is here: http://publikz.com/one-more-task-rounded-selection-in-jquery/)
but with *round* (or ellipse) selection.

Can anybody help me? Maybe your have made this in past. Need it to select round (ie have center & radius)

Thanks, Arsen

PS. Here is rectangular example:

Comment: I can't think of any plugin that does this... so you might end up needing to use canvas to do this. Check out Raphaël (http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html)

Comment: Your know - i will check this. Very good idea to make canvas... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example.
Drag the yellow pointer ...
Round is also draggable ...
http://publikz.com/projects/roundsel-v2/

Yes, is not a finished yet, but anyone can take idea... and this is possible.

Comment: Not, buyer just want check possibility, and do not make order that time.

Comment: May i take your code an try to continue it to create a working "round selection" tool?

Comment: why not,  pls - take & proceed :) If this is possible - pls show what your will get as a result.

Comment: yes, but this still have problem - left/right resize markers do not moves, when your change height. Same with with changing & top/bottom markers...

Comment: yeah thats right, this is planned for one of the next releases.

Comment: Nice, this one i was not able to do, was done. Taking look & making link to myself site ...